# Write list of random numbers to file. No Instance for (Show (IO a0))

Tags: haskell, random

I am trying to write to file a list of random Integers in a file. There seems to be a problem with `writeFile` here. When I use my function `randomFile` it says `no instance for (Show (IO a0))`. I see `writeFile` doesn't print anything to screen but `IO()`, so when I call the function `randomFile 1 2 3` it says `no Instance for Show (IO a0)` but actually I just want to execute the function and not have to print anything but how can I avoid this problem. I might be making a lot of errors here. Any help.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import System.Random

randNo mind maxd = randomRIO (mind,maxd)
randomFile mind maxd noe = do
  let l=(replicate (fromInteger(noe ^ noe)) ( mind `randNo` maxd))
  writeFile "RFile.txt" (show l)
```

Comment: Does the question title suit the question appropriately.

Comment: So, do I understand it correctly that ``randomFile`` is supposed to write ``noe`` randoms in the range ``[mind, maxd]`` to ``RFile.txt``? The ``let l ...`` line is a bit confusing.

Comment: Ok after multiple edits I kind of got to that. So after that comment I realized there was no need for a foldl. randomFile is supposed to write `noe ^2` (no of expressions) to the file, each expression will contain multiple no of  integers (yet to be done).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what IO is. If you haven't done it, I strongly recommend going through the [Input and Output section of Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).

`IO` doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `print`. In Haskell every entry in memory that was made by your own code is considered "pure" while any entry that touches the rest of the computer lives in IO (with some exceptions you will learn about over time).

We model IO using something called a Monad. Which you will learn more about the longer you do Haskell. To understand this, let's look at an example of some code that does and doesn't use IO:

```
noIOused :: Int -> Int
noIOused x = x + 5

usesIO :: Int -> IO Int
usesIO x = print x >> return (x + 5)

usesIO2 :: Int -> IO Int
usesIO2 x = do
    print x
    return (x + 5)
```

The first function is "pure". The second and third functions have an IO "effect" that comes in the form of printing to the screen. `usesIO` and `usesIO2` are just 2 different ways of doing the same thing (it's the same code but with different syntax). I'll use the second format, called `do` notation from here.

Here are some other ways you could have had IO effects:

```
add5WithFile :: Int -> IO Int
add5WithFile x = do
    writeFile "someFile.txt" (show x)
    return (x + 5)
```

Notice that in that function we didn't print anything, we wrote a file. But writing a file has a side effect and interacts with the rest of the system. So any value we return has to get wrapped in IO.

```
addRandom :: Int -> IO Int
addRandom x = do
    y <- randomRIO (1,10)
    return (x + y)
```

In `addRandom` we called `randomRIO (1,10)`. But the problem is that randomRIO doesn't return an `Int`. It returns an `IO Int`. Why? Because in order to get true randomness we need to interact with the system in some way. To get around that, we have to temporarily strip away the IO. That's where this line comes in:

```
y <- randomRIO (1,10)
```

That `<-` arrow tells us that we want a `y` value outside of IO. For as long as we remain inside the `do` syntax that `y` value is going to be "pure". Now we can use it just like any other value.

So for example we couldn't do this:

```
let w = x + (randomRIO (1,10))
```

Because that would be trying to add `Int` to `IO Int`. And unfortunately our `+` function doesn't know how to do that. So first we have to "bind" the result of `randomRIO` to `y` before we can add it to `x`.

Now let's look at your code:

```
let l=(replicate (fromInteger(noe ^ noe)) ( mind `randNo` maxd))
writeFile "RFile.txt" (show l)
```

The type of `l` is actually `IO a0`. It's `a0` because you haven't told the compiler what kind of number you want. So it doesn't know if you want a fraction, a double, a big integer or whatever.

So the first problem is to let the compiler know a little bit more about what kind of random number you want. We do this by adding a type annotation:

```
randNo :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
randNo mind maxd = randomRIO (mind,maxd)
```

Now both you and the compiler knows what kind of value `randNo` is.

Now we need to "bind" that value inside of the `do` notation to temporarily escape IO. You might think that would be simple, like this:

```
randomFile mind maxd noe = do
  l <- replicate (fromInteger(noe ^ noe)) ( mind `randNo` maxd)
  writeFile "RFile.txt" (show l)
```

Surely that will "bind" the `IO Int` to `l` right? Unfortunately not. The problem here is that `replicate` is a function of the form `Int -> a -> [a]`. That is, given a number and a type, it will give you a list of that type.

If you give `replicate` an `IO Int` it's going to make `[IO Int]`. That actually looks more like this: `List (IO Int)` except we use `[]` as syntactic sugar for lists. Unfortunately if we want to "bind" an `IO` value to something with `<-` it has to be the out-most type.

So what you need is a way to turn an `[IO Int]` into an `IO [Int]`. There are two ways to do that. If we [put `\[IO a\] -> IO \[a\]` into Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BIO%20a%5D%20-%3E%20IO%20%5Ba%5D) we get this:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

As I mentioned before, we generalise IO to something called a Monad. Which isn't really that big a deal, we could pretend that `sequence` has this signature: `sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]` and it would be the same thing just specialised to IO.

Now your function would be done like this:

```
randomFile mind maxd noe = do
  l <- sequence (replicate (fromInteger(noe ^ noe)) ( mind `randNo` maxd))
  writeFile "RFile.txt" (show l)
```

But a `sequence` followed by `replicate` is something people have to do all the time. So someone went and made a function called `replicateM`:

```
replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]
```

Now we can write your function like this:

```
randomFile mind maxd noe = do
  l <- replicateM (fromInteger(noe ^ noe)) ( mind `randNo` maxd)
  writeFile "RFile.txt" (show l)
```

And for some real Haskell magic, you can write all 3 lines of code in a single line, like this:

```
randomFile mind maxd noe = randomRIO >>= writeFile "RFile.txt" . replicateM (fromInteger(noe ^ noe))
```

If that looks like gibberish to you, then there's a lot you need to learn. Here is the suggested path:

1. If you haven't already, start from the beginning with [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)
2. Then learn about how [You could have invented Monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html)
3. Then learn more about how to use [randomness in Haskell](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Libraries/Random)
4. Finally see if you can complete the [20 intermediate Haskell exercises](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/DanBurton/20-intermediate-exercises)

Comment: I kind of know those concepts which I have freshly learnt but have lacked any coding practice to realize it practically. That is an excellently written answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: The more I read, the more I find out that everyone learns about Monads differently. Glad you found a tutorial that works for you! If you want to test your knowledge, make sure you go through the 20 intermediate exercises.